# SSIS oracle NUMBER vs sql server mapping

Tags: ssis, sqldatatypes

We're developing a package to replicate data from an ORACLE DB into an SQL Server one. We're struggling with what we believe to be data type mappings issue.
When running the package the following error is thrown:

`Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, ORADB1[2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "ORADB1" failed because error code 0x80131938 occurred, and the error row disposition on "ORADB1.Outputs[ADO NET Source Output].Columns[UNIT_PRICE]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.`

In the source, the column UNIT_PRICE is of data type NUMBER, with length 22:

[image]

This is a little sample of the source data:

[image]

Initially we've set the column UNIT_PRICE to FLOAT in the target. For all NUMBER columns actually. As we've little to none experience with SSIS, could you tell us the appropriate mapping for each NUMBER column?
thanks

Comment: Never use float unless you have a good reason (you are measuring distances to stars or distances between molecules). Anyway I googled and found some information for you here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/GMSWN/apa.htm#GMSWN400

Comment: Also this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-data-type-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Generally, NUMBER(22) in Oracle would be `NUMERIC(22,0)` in SQL Server. Beware of Oracle `NUMBER` without any size. This usually auto maps to `FLOAT` (depending on the Oracle driver) but I would recommend using a better data type (i.e. specific `NUMERIC(p,s)` ) f you have some idea of the possible data ranges.